# excel column with formula does not get import into datatable

Tags: excel, aspose

I used aspose to insert a new column and added a MID formula for that column then saved it locally. It worked as expected, however when I tried to retrieve this file again and attempted to store it in a datatable, the new column with MID formula showed up as blank. For testing purposes, I went through the process again and tested it with a different formula like SUM and it worked fine. It seems like it doesn't like the MID formula. Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I am Social Media Developer at Aspose. The issue mentioned above has already been fixed in the latest version of Aspose.Cells for .NET v8.0.0. Following is the sample code for reference:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

//Adding a sample value to "A1" cell
worksheet.Cells["A1"].PutValue("Full Name");

//Adding a sample value to "A2" cell
worksheet.Cells["A2"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A3" cell
worksheet.Cells["A3"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A4" cell
worksheet.Cells["A4"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A5" cell
worksheet.Cells["A5"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A6" cell
worksheet.Cells["A6"].PutValue("First Last");


//Adding a sample value to "A7" cell
worksheet.Cells["A7"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A8" cell
worksheet.Cells["A8"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A9" cell
worksheet.Cells["A9"].PutValue("First Last");

//Adding a sample value to "A10" cell
worksheet.Cells["A10"].PutValue("First Last");

int newColPos = worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1;

worksheet.Cells.InsertColumn(newColPos);

string colName = CellsHelper.ColumnIndexToName(newColPos);

string fullNameCol = CellsHelper.ColumnIndexToName(0);

string formula = "=MID(" + fullNameCol + ":" + fullNameCol + ", FIND(" + "\"" + " \"" + "," + fullNameCol + ":" + fullNameCol + "), LEN(" + fullNameCol + ":" + fullNameCol + "))";

colName = colName + "2"; //get second row (skip header row)

worksheet.Cells[colName].SetSharedFormula(formula, 5, 1);

workbook.CalculateFormula();

//Save the workbook for checking
workbook.Save(@"C:\Data\out.xlsx");

System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString(0, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);
```

As this issue was still unanswered, hopefully this reply will help anyone facing a similar issue.